# Modern OpenGL - Can attributes be made conditional in shader?

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, vertex-shader

C# / OpenTK.

I have been having trouble finding a good way to combine different geometry types in a scene. For efficiency reasons I have been trying to use the same shader and single VAO/VBO for mixed primitive types (triangles, lines and potentially line strips). Not sure whether this is possible/desirable.

The main problem I have got is that the triangles are instanced and their inputs into the vertex shader need to be vertices and normals. However the lines are not instanced, do not require lighting, but are different colors, so their required inputs into the vertex shader need to be vertices and colors. So in one case I want normals in the shader, in the other case I want colors.

One solution would be to make this conditional in the shader. I have got this at the top of my vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexColor;
```

If I try to make this conditional (i.e. location 2 = normal or colour depending on primitive type) I get a syntax error. Not particularly surprised since these lines are definitions, outside `main()`. I presume an If statement is not allowed there.

Another solution would be a separate shader, but I would prefer to avoid the duplication if possible.

Currently I have split the polygons and lines into two separate buffers, since this seems logical. Can I render them using the same shader (without adding dummy values for padding, which could make the data structure consistent but wouldn't be very efficient)? Ideally I would have a way to tell it that I am passing in normals in one case and vertices in another.

There is also some behaviour that I don't understand. I thought, based on everything I can find on the subject, that the `index` argument in `VertexAttribPointer` had to correspond to the `location` in the shader. But this is not how it behaves. I have got vertex data which I am giving an index of 2 (seen in the code below towards the end of `InitVertexBuffers`) which corresponds to color in the shader - yet the geometry of this is correctly rendered.

So my questions are:

1) Is it possible to make the `layout` definitions in the shader conditional?

2) Should I keep data for different primitive types in separate buffers?

3) Does the first argument (`location`) of `VertexAttribPointer` not tell OpenGL how to treat each set of data? If not, how is this determined?

```
private void InitVertexBuffers()
{

    int floatSize = sizeof(float);

    VBO1 = GL.GenBuffer();
    VAO1 = GL.GenVertexArray();

    // Bind Vertex Array Object...
    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);

    // Copy our vertices array in a buffer for OpenGL to use...
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO1);

    List<int> array_lengths = new List<int>() {
        vertices.Length * floatSize };

    // Calculate and store offset pointers...
    List<int> array_offsets = new List<int>() {
        0 };

    // Set vertex attributes pointers...
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * floatSize, (IntPtr)0, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)0, array_lengths[0], vertices);

    // Sensor offset vertices...
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, 0);

    // Normals...
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, 3 * floatSize);

    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    VBO2 = GL.GenBuffer();
    VAO2 = GL.GenVertexArray();
    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO2);

    array_lengths = new List<int>() {
        line_vertices.Length * floatSize,
        axis_widget_vertices.Length * floatSize,
        };

    array_offsets = new List<int>() {
        0,
        array_lengths[0] };

    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (line_vertices.Length + axis_widget_vertices.Length) * floatSize, (IntPtr)0, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)array_offsets[0], array_lengths[0], line_vertices);
    GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)array_offsets[1], array_lengths[1], axis_widget_vertices);

    // Individual lines...
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, array_offsets[0]);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, array_offsets[0] + 3 * floatSize);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, array_offsets[1]);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(3, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * floatSize, array_offsets[1] + 3 * floatSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // zero to three
    {
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }

    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest); // enable z buffer

}

private void Draw()
{

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);
    SetBool(Handle, "instanced", 1);
    GL.DrawArraysInstanced(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 6, allNodes.Count);
    SetBool(Handle, "instanced", 0);

    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
    SetBool(Handle, "use_lighting", 0);
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Lines, 0, line_vertices.Length / 6);
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Lines, line_vertices.Length / 6, axis_widget_vertices.Length / 6);
    SetBool(Handle, "use_lighting", 1);

    glControl1.SwapBuffers();

}

string vertexShaderSource =
    "# version 330 core\n" +
    "uniform mat4 model;" +
    "uniform mat4 view;" +
    "uniform mat4 projection;" +
    "uniform bool instanced;" +
    $"uniform vec3 offsets[{ allNodes.Count }];" +
    $"uniform vec3 colors[{ allNodes.Count }];" +
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;" +
    "layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;" +
    "layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexColor;" +
    "out vec3 color_out;" +
    "out vec3 FragPos;" +
    "out vec3 Normal;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "vec3 offset = offsets[gl_InstanceID];" +
    "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos + offset, 1.0);" +
    "FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos + offset, 1.0));" +
    "Normal = vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 1.0));" + // (normal has to be rotated the same as the model)
    "if (instanced) {" +
    "color_out = colors[gl_InstanceID];" +
    "} else {" +
    "color_out = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
    "}" +
    "}";
```

Comment: "*I would prefer to avoid the duplication if possible.*" It's not clear what that would mean in this context. If one mechanism of rendering uses a provided color, and another uses a fixed, precompiled, these are different shaders with different implementations. Even moreso for normals, since those involve lighting, which means lighting parameters typically passed as uniforms, as well as the shader code needed to do lighting computations. How much "duplication" is there really going to be for these very different rendering circumstances?

Comment: I was mainly referring to duplication of code. So separate shaders would be the way to go?

Comment: Looking at it again, I take the point that even the shader code for the two cases wouldn't have all that much overlap

Answer (score 0):

I am going to largely answer my own question here. Thanks to the comment from Nicol Bolas which made me think that separate shaders would be appropriate. I have implemented this idea and it does seem the best approach.

I have now got separate shaders for the polygon and line data. Both pairs of shaders are initialised at the start and a single call to `GL.UseProgram()` switches between them. This has enabled me to greatly simplify the shaders for rendering lines.

I think(?) the problem I was having understanding the `VertexAttribPointer()` index numbers is explained by the fact that the third and fourth calls I was making to it were actually redundant. Since the data was sequential in the buffer, and `VertexAttribPointer()` just points to the start of that data, the first two calls were enough to define the location of the vertex and colour data respectively. The calls to `GL.DrawArrays()` then identified exactly which chunk of that data to use.

Some revised code:

```
public void Render() {

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    GL.UseProgram(Handle); // shaders for polygons
    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);
    SetBool(Handle, "instanced", 1);
    GL.DrawArraysInstanced(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 6, allNodes.Count);
    SetBool(Handle, "instanced", 0);

    GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
    GL.UseProgram(Handle2); // shaders for lines

    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Lines, 0, line_vertices.Length / 6);

    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Lines, line_vertices.Length / 6, axis_widget_vertices.Length / 6);

    glControl1.SwapBuffers();
}
```

---

```
string vertexShaderSource = // for polygons
    "# version 330 core\n" +
    "uniform mat4 model;" +
    "uniform mat4 view;" +
    "uniform mat4 projection;" +
    "uniform bool instanced;" +
    $"uniform vec3 offsets[{ allNodes.Count }];" +
    $"uniform vec3 colors[{ allNodes.Count }];" +
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;" +
    "layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;" +
    "out vec3 color_out;" +
    "out vec3 FragPos;" +
    "out vec3 Normal;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "vec3 offset = offsets[gl_InstanceID];" +
    "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos + offset, 1.0);" +
    "FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos + offset, 1.0));" +
    "Normal = vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 1.0));" + // (normal has to be rotated the same as the model)
    "if (instanced) {" +
    "color_out = colors[gl_InstanceID];" +
    "} else {" +
    "color_out = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
    "}" +
    "}";

string vertexShader2 = // for lines
    "# version 330 core\n" +
    "uniform mat4 model;" +
    "uniform mat4 view;" +
    "uniform mat4 projection;" +
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;" +
    "layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;" +
    "out vec3 color_out;" +
    "out vec3 FragPos;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);" +
    "FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));" +
    "color_out = vertexColor;" +
    "}";

string fragmentShaderSource = // for polygons
    "#version 330 core\n" +
    "in vec3 FragPos;" +
    "in vec3 Normal;" +
    "in vec3 color_out;" +
    "out vec4 FragColor;" +
    "uniform vec3 objectColor;" +
    "uniform vec3 lightColor;" +
    "uniform vec3 lightPos;" +
    "uniform bool use_lighting;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "if (use_lighting) {" +
    "float ambientStrength = 0.5;" +
    "vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;" +
    "vec3 norm = Normal;" +
    "vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);" +
    "float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);" +
    "vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;" +
    "vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse) * color_out;" + // color_out = object colour from vertex shader
    "FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);" +
    "} else {" +
    "FragColor = vec4(color_out, 1.0);" +
    "}" +
    "}";

string fragmentShader2 = // for lines
    "#version 330 core\n" +
    "in vec3 FragPos;" +
    "in vec3 color_out;" +
    "out vec4 FragColor;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "FragColor = vec4(color_out, 1.0);" +
    "}";
```